# Limit content to a certain logged user

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We want to achieve to limit a specific content on a custom theme in WordPress, just reading his user-role in the body content of the page.

I tried to do so with JS (I know it is not secure), but did not manage to obtain what we want.

What we want to achieve is that a popup form should be showing up for certain kind of user (already managed to make a user-class-role available on the body of the HTML page) who navigate on Premium tab on the single listing page of the theme and are not logged in or not allowed to do so without paying an affiliation fee (of course hiding the content in the background)

Here you can find a page example https://golfrevo.it/struttura/circolo-golf-e-tennis-rapallo/ and a screenshot of the tab below

[image: Hide premium tab]

This is instead the code I tried to implement

```
jQuery('.c27-submit-listing-form .account-sign-in .button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery('#sign-in-modal').modal('show');
});

// Force login for bookings
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var tabs = [
        '_tab_1',
        'PREMIUM',
        'premium'
    ];

    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        $('body:not(.role-golfer_trial).single-listing .profile-menu li a:contains("' + tab + '")').unbind();
        $('body:not(.role-golfer_trial).single-listing').on('click', '.profile-menu li a:contains("' + tab + '")', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('You must be premium useres to view this content');
            $('#sign-in-modal').modal();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try it again without fancy quotes

Comment: Hiding the content in the background is a terrible idea.  People (like me) will simply fix the view so they see it.  You should only serve what you want the user to have access to - this should be done server side.

Comment: `‘`, `’`, `“` and `”` are invalid string delimiters in JS. Use `"` and `'` only. Also remove the spaces around the hyphens in your  selectors.

Comment: there are a handful of plugins that do so, they are called paywall.

Comment: @Archer I do that all the time. Sites which block my view with some overlays until I register (Quora), I just remove it in the DOM and add CSS to re-enable scorllbars

Comment: @Nope better yet, use an extension like Stylish or TamperMonkey to remove the overlays permanently with injected CSS

Comment: Do you code using Microsoft Word?

Comment: @Nope I have several scripts and CSS files that are applied by Stylish and TamperMonkey for sites I regularly visit.  Some sites I have bookmarklets that "fix" them.  This is a bad idea, but if the content is worth viewing then I fully support the OP in their approach :D

Comment: Not hard to modify wordpress template using a child theme